# Regular expression help in Java dice rolling program

Tags: java, calculator, dice

I've been at this all day and I can't for the life of me figure out what I am doing wrong. The code crashes my Android emulator. What I am attempting to do is write a dice rolling program, and I have it working with dice rolled as single entities, but I'm trying to process dice rolls like 3d6 or 5d4. The call to singleRoll rolls a single die at a time, and I'm trying to break down a longer equation into simpler bits...   "3d4+5-13d6+7d8+9"

bbs.randInt returns [0,diceSize).

```
public int multiPartRoll(String roll) {
        String[] parts = roll.split("(?=[+-])"); //split by +-, keeping them
        int total = 0;

        // TODO: Replace 5d4 with d4+d4+d4+d4+d4
        for (String partOfRoll : parts) { //roll each dice specified


            if (partOfRoll.matches("\\d+d\\d+")) {
                String[] splitString = (partOfRoll.split("d"));
                int times = Integer.getInteger(splitString[0]);
                int die = Integer.getInteger(splitString[1]);
                int i;
                for (i = 0; i < times; i++) {
                    String rollStr = "d" + die;
                    total += singleRoll(rollStr);
                }
            }
            else {
                total += singleRoll(partOfRoll);   
            }

        }
        return total;
    }

public int singleRoll(String roll) {
        int di = roll.indexOf('d');
        if (di == -1) //case where has no 'd'
            return Integer.parseInt(roll);
        int diceSize = Integer.parseInt(roll.substring(di + 1)); //value of string after 'd'
        int result = bbs.randInt(diceSize) + 1; //roll the dice
        if (roll.startsWith("-")) //negate if nessasary
            result = -result;
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so, post the stack trace.

Comment: where's the `singleRoll(String)` method? Could you post that code as well?

Comment: `public int singleRoll(String roll) {
        int di = roll.indexOf('d');
        if (di == -1) //case where has no 'd'
            return Integer.parseInt(roll);
        int diceSize = Integer.parseInt(roll.substring(di + 1)); //value of string after 'd'
        int result = bbs.randInt(diceSize) + 1; //roll the dice
        if (roll.startsWith("-")) //negate if nessasary
            result = -result;
        return result;
    }`

Comment: Sorry, I'm new. I don't know how to post code in a comment.

Comment: Edit your main post with that code.

Comment: Hi, have you tested the result of the splitting into parts with your test string (3d4+5-13d6+7d8+9)?
The result seems to me not suitable for processing:
`3d4`
`+5`
`-13d6`
`+7d8`
`+9`

Look especially at the first token: it is the only one which can possibly match the regexp in the loop (and cause trouble not having a sign prepended).

Comment: @BugProtectionActivist, I have tested it with similar strings though not exactly this one. It always fails the "xdx" code, everything else seems to work properly when I run it through the processor. (e.g. 2+d12+d8+4-13)

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the use of the wrong Integer parsing method.

Try replacing all of occurrences of

`Integer.getInteger`

with

`Integer.parseInt`

the method you used does not convert a String into an Integer: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#getInteger%28java.lang.String%29

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Let introduce `Dice` interface:

```
interface Dice {

    int roll();
}
```

And two classes `NDice` that is 'normal dice':

```
class NDice implements Dice {

    private final int nb;
    private final int sides;
    private Random r = new Random();

    NDice(String[] desc) {
        this.nb = Integer.parseInt(desc[0]);
        this.sides = Integer.parseInt(desc[1]);
    }

    @Override
    public int roll() {
        return nb < 0 ? -1 : 1 * IntStream.generate(() -> r.nextInt(sides) + 1).limit(Math.abs(nb)).sum();
    }
}
```

And `CDice` that is 'constant dice':

```
class CDice implements Dice {
    private int constant;

    public CDice(int constant) {
        this.constant = constant;
    }

    @Override
    public int roll() {
        return constant;
    }
}
```

Then we could introduce method to parse `rollDescription` into collection of dices and roll this dices:

```
static int roll(String rollDescription) {
    String[] parts = rollDescription.split("(?=[+-])");
    return Arrays.stream(parts)
            .map(s -> {
                if (s.contains("d")) {
                    return new NDice(s.split("d"));
                }
                return new CDice(Integer.parseInt(s));
            }).map(Dice::roll).reduce(0, (a, b) -> a + b);
}
```

Now short explanation:

- `CDice` we need only to consolidate interface
- in expression `nb < 0 ? -1 : 1 * ... Math.abs(nb)` we need to support `-` before number of rolls (`nb`).
- I omitted meta information about rolls. If you need you could introduce class `RollResult` that contains result and some extra information about dices.
- Naming could be better
- static method `roll` need 'home class'. `Dice` interface is nice, but not perfect place for that.